# Observable passed through Angular 2 service won't fire when subscribed to

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs, angularfire2

I'm building an app with Ionic 2 using firebase as the back end and connecting with angularfire2.  I'm trying to get the root page to change when the authentication changes state.

The method in my service that returns the observable looks like this

```
getUserData() {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(authData => {
      if (authData) {
        console.log("Auth Changed");
        observer.next(userData);
      } else {
        observer.error();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I'm calling the service in my app.conponent file to change the root page

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.auth.getUserData().subscribe(data => {
    console.log("ngOnit");
      if (!this.isAppInitialized) {
        this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
        this.isAppInitialized = true;
      }
      this.user = data;
    }, err => {
      this.nav.setRoot(LoginEmailPage);
    });
  });
}
```

The console reads as below the first time after the page resets

```
"Auth Changed"
"ngOnit"
```

but then after another login attempt I only get

```
"Auth Changed"
```

The method in the subscription isn't firing.

If I subscribe to another observable it clogs the ngOnit every time so I think it has something to do with the observable I created.

Is there something wrong with the observable I created?

Comment: how are you sending observer parameter?  Is it a subject?

Comment: There's no need to wrap auth with another observable. You can use it directly in your component. Instead of `this.auth.getUserData().subscribe(...)` you can use `this.af.auth.subscribe(...)`, and maybe add filter `this.af.auth.filter(Boolean).subscribe(...)`

Comment: I think I need to work off the same af (angularfire) reference for all of my pages.  I tried changing to this.af.auth.subscribe in the app.component but I still didn't get it to fire.

Comment: I noticed it does work when the user logs out but not when they log in...So the err will fire but not the next()